# Why does mmap return an invalid address but not an error code?

Tags: c, file-handling, mmap, memcpy, bus-error

In this small program I am attempting to write to a file using `mmap`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

typedef struct stat stat_t;

int main() {
    int total_size = 10;
    int fd = open("res.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open() Program failure");
    }
    char *res_ptr = mmap(NULL, total_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(res_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("Error Number  mmap %d\n", errno);
        perror("mmap() Program failure");
    }

    memcpy(res_ptr, "ASDFG", 5);
    munmap(res_ptr, total_size);
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Neither `open` nor `mmap` return an error, but `mmap` seems to be returning an invalid or nonexistent address.

The eclipse debugger says that it can't access that memory address.
[image]

Finally, the attempt to execute write something to that address with `memcpy` causes a Bus error.
[image]

So, why did `mmap` return this apparently invalid address?